# destructor ignore string assignment

Tags: c++, string, destructor

I have created a program in C++ for a class, and one of the requirements is to output a string when certain parts of the program have been called. For most of these I have simply assigned a string to a member variable and then outputted that variable. I wanted to know is it possible for me to assign the string in a destructor and then output that string? When I try it, it outputs nothing.

ie:

```
Class
   private:
   string output;

~Class {
   output = "destructor has fired!";
}

int main(){
   cout << class.message;
}
```

This is pseudocode so please ignore syntax mistakes/missing pieces.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. Do you know what destructor is?

Comment: You should show what you actually tried instead of this pseudocode.

Comment: @NathanOliver I do know what I tried, and it's not necessary to have every single piece of code exactly right to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. This is not a "what's wrong with my code" question, in which case, accurate code would be necessary

Comment: Technically you can store the message in a static field or a global variable, but if I were you I'd write the message directly to the `cout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is possible to output a message in the destructor, to know that it has fired, and one way to do it is this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class C{
    string output; // by default private
public:
    C(){}
    ~C() { cout << output << endl; }
    void setString(const string& s) {
        output = s;
    }

};  

int main()
{
    {
        C s;
        s.setString("Destructor has fired");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, I was trying to avoid doing direct output from a class but it seems that this is the only way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, this is what you are expected to do. Note: no member variable, direct calls to `std::cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class C{
public:
    C() {
        cout << "C ctor" << endl; 
    }
    ~C() {
        cout << "C dtor" << endl; 
    }
};  

int main()
{
    {
        C s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was originally doing however I figured it'd be better practice to avoid direct output but maybe that's not possible in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: @AngelaKay, it's a better practice to separate the output from everything else **when** this output is the main output of the program intended to be seen by the user, but when the output is a log message (i.e. a notification about an event that is meaningful only to the creator of the program e.g. a creation of an object) it's better to call the logger directly than to rely on other parts of the program to extract the message.

Comment: @AngelaKay Rationale: 1. If you don't call the logger directly, you have to store messages waiting to be logged in every class. It means creating an additional field in every class that isn't related to the primary purpose of the class.

Comment: 2. It also means you have to create an infrastructure to extract this messages from objects. It's a lot more code that can contain bugs. 3. If you log directly, you see events in a chronological order, but if you use a complicated infrastructure, you have to complicate it even further to make it output events in chronological order. 4. The most valuable log messages are ones that are produced immediately before your program crashes unexpectedly. if you complicate the dispatch of the log messages, there is a high chance that your program terminates before having a chance to log this messages.

Comment: Note: in real programs the log output is usually done by writing to a file, not by printing messages in the console.

Comment: Separating the user interface from other parts of your program is better because it allows changing the output w/o modifying the algorithm and modifying the algorithm w/o having to rewrite the user interface. This isn't the case with logging: no matter how hard you try it'll stay closely coupled with the implementation of your program. Also: the logging system is simple and unlikely to change so you aren't gaining anything by trying to decouple it from the rest of the program. A simple function `log(message)` or `log(severity, message)` is usually sufficient even in a very big project.